# xcolor package problem

Tags: tables, color, miktex, tabu, longtabu

I am trying to color the rows in a document. The code I am using is as below

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{grey1}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{grey2}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\taburowcolors[2] 2 {grey2..grey2}
\begin{longtabu}[H]{XXl}
    \caption{Chemicals and Reagents}\\[2mm]
    \rowcolor{grey1}
    \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Reference}\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

When running this on overleaf everything is fine but using TeXstudio and MikTex2.9 with the latest updates doesn't perform the coloring of rows. Here is my [log](https://ufile.io/lu3en7j7) file. I'd greatly appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: tabu package is broken. don't use it if you don't have to

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: What can I use instead of tabu?

Comment: instead of tabu, I'd use a normal tabular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question has been posted in *GitHub*, see [Simplest MWE to have an alternating row color #18](https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/issues/18). The proposed solution for the current version of `tabu` (`v2.9 2019/01/11`) comments some commands, see [Figure](https://github.com/meneldal/tabu/commit/2318a9d45800bd0f100022b44bad63c71a831f3d#diff-67337af7d77f6aaa90c39b744c246c6f). For further details check please the solution provided in `GitHub`.

[image]

I try this fix in `tabu.sty` and does what you are looking for. Maybe it will be fixed in the next `release-2.10` of `tabu`

Answer (score 2):

using `tabularx` instead of the broken `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{grey1}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{grey2}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\rowcolors{2}{red}{blue}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Chemicals and Reagents}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXl}
    \rowcolor{grey1}
    \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Reference}\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
    Whatever & from whomever & 123456789\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```